# How do I get 'TCP' to work with left_on and right_on

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, metadata

I am working on a project for my online class. We are supposed to turn some data back into metadata. However, when I tried to do one of the steps shown,

```
ecco_metadata_w_counts = ecco_metadata.merge(calculated_data_df, left_on='TCP', right_on='TCP')
```

I would get the response

> KeyError: 'TCP'

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

How do I get 'TCP' to work?

When I put in

```
ecco_metadata.head()
```

and

```
calculated_data_df.head()
```

I would get the response

```
DocName Author_original Author 1    Author 2    Author 3    Author 4    Author 5    Author 6    Wikidata ID sex or gender   ... position held   religion or worldview   languages spoken, written or signed movement    member of   Number of authors   Date    Title   Pages   Source
```

for ecco_metadata
and

```
TCP total_words discrete_count  variance
```

for calculated_data_df

Comment: What is `ecco_metadata`? Is this the [Ecco Group](https://www.ecco-group.org/analysis-tools.htm) tools?

Comment: ecco_metadata is metadata about 18th century texts.

Comment: What type of data is it? Is it a pandas dataframe? You didn't tag this `pandas`.

Comment: The error message indicates that there's no TCP column in `ecco_metadata` and/or `calculated_data_df`. Can you show the output of `ecco_metadata.head()` and `calculated_data_df.head()`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the pandas dataframe tag. The 'ecco_metadata.head()' is   
 'DocName Author_original Author 1 Author 2 Author 3 Author 4 Author 5 Author 6 Wikidata ID sex or gender ... position held religion or worldview languages spoken, written or signed movement member of Number of authors Date Title Pages Source' and the output for '
calculated_data_df.head()' is 'TCP total_words discrete_count variance'

Comment: Add the details to the question, not a comment, so you can format them readably.

Comment: But I don't see a `TCP` column there.

Comment: `TCP` is in the `calculated_data_df.head().

Comment: `left_on='TCP'` means to use the TCP column from the left dataframe, which is `ecco_metadata`.